# I can not start ubuntu with USB

Tags: windows, ubuntu

The PC is Windows. I wanted the ubuntu environment, I put the ubuntu iso file on the USB. After that, if I try to restart and start ubuntu, I get an error like the following.

[Like this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI3Jh.jpg)
The details of the error are the two statements below.(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system[figure ex.) 135.392108] usb 3-4: device descriptor ewad / all, error -110I tried variously, but it was useless. (I tried BIOS etc. but it was useless.What I want to do is to have Ubuntu portable on the USB. However, I want to prevent any Windows from being broken.I do not know the meaning of 2.0 / 3.0 on the USB drive side and socket side.The one that I use is USB 3.0.Ubuntu version is 18.04.2. The iso. file was loaded with Universal-USB-installer.I tried both UEFI and LEGACY mode with BOOT on the BIOS screen, but it was useless.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: this seems more appropriate in askubuntu.com